# Django: Not able to access the object attribute on the model class in View.py

Tags: python, django

Django: Not able to access the object attribute on the model class

I am busy building a Django App that returns a set of requirements from the database. I am however getting ab ObjectDoesNotExist exception in the View.py. I am making use of Visual Studio 2015. I will appreciate all help in resolving this error.

Below is the code in the Models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Requirement_Matrix(models.Model):    
    RequirementName = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

In Views.py the intellisense in Visual Studio 2015 is saying that objects (Line 12) is unknown type. When you run the program it raises an object does not exist exception.

```
01 from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
02 from ScopeManagement.models import Requirement_Matrix
03
04
05 def index(request):
06    # Query the database for a list of requirements for a specific project.
07    # Place the list in our Requirement_dict dictionary which will be passed to the 
08  #template engine.
09    
10    try:
11
12        Requirement_list = Requirement_Matrix.objects.all() ### <- Visual Studio 2015 
13  # is saying that objects is unknown type and then it raises an object does 
14  # not exist exception
15
16        Requirement_dict = {'requirements': Requirement_list}
17
18    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
19        print ('Does Not Exist!')
20    
21    # Render the response and send it back
22    return render(request, 'ScopeManagement/index.html', Requirement_dict)
```

When you however query the model through the python manage.py shell it does return a value:

```
python manage.py shell
>>> from ScopeManagement.models import Requirement_Matrix
>>> Requirement_Matrix.objects.all()
[<Requirement_Matrix: Requirement 1>]
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: Firstly, what intellisense believes about the code is completely irrelevant; you should ignore it. However, that code is not capable of raising that exception; `.all()` will never raise DoesNotExist. What is the actual error you are seeing when you go to that view?

Comment: Thank you, you are right. When I debugged the code I found that it was on the Requirement_dict field which I changed to context_dict and then I could see that it is populating context_dict with values from the database.